# how to set textfield placeholder value from localisable.string file in objective c.?

Tags: objective-c

I can't set placeholder for textfield.I have to change it accoding to the language choosen for app,so that it should set from localizable string file.

I tried this code

```
_emailTextField.placeholder = NSLocalizedString(@"EMAIL_OR_MOBILE", nil);
```

but it is not working.

Comment: how you are changing language ?

Comment: now I just change the application language in edit scheme.but when the time it became single language the code effect is same.i can't set through localizable string file.

Comment: can u share any image of your code?

Comment: this is my controller class's viewdidload.labels are working fine but textfield place holder didnt set.                                                                      - (void)viewDidLoad {
     _loginTitle
    .text = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"LOGIN", nil), @(1000000)];
    [_loginButton setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"LOGIN", nil) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       _emailTextField.placeholder = NSLocalizedString(@"EMAIL_OR_MOBILE", nil);
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

Comment: solved the issue.set placeholder value at storyboard's string file.Anwy thank u for the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is perfectly fine. Check that:

1. Your strings files is called `Localizable.strings`
2. It is copied into the application bundle. Check the 'Copy' build phahse, it should be listed there.
3. The key `@"EMAIL_OR_MOBILE"` is presented in all languages of the strings file.
4. Try cleaning the project.

For me it was the first one.

Edit: in the project info tab, under Localization, did you add your second language?